# How to create a container from an image

Tags: docker, containers, ubuntu

I have this following image:

```
REPOSITORY               TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch   18.04-py3   c3555fec4fe6   3 years ago   5.9GB
```

The goal is to use Ubuntu 18.04 with CUDA 10.2. Now I want to create a container with this image. How can I do that? The guides online didn't make much sense to me as I'm pretty new to docker.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, there are a lot of options you can pass in to docker, but if you just want to run the code in the container as written:

`docker run nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:18.04-py3`

or

`docker run c3555fec4fe6`

or even

`docker run c3`

you can give your docker images a more reasonable name with

`docker image tag nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:18.04-py3 pytorch`

and run that with

`docker run pytorch`

---

see

- `man docker-run`
- `man docker-image-tag`

and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: I did `docker image tag nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:18.04-py3 pytorch` and then tried to do `sudo docker run pytorch` but its giving me `docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir /var/lib/docker/containers/22346b8352726ee06780791c3ee37c138b8c4b3d600225502266916e57902c56: no such file or directory.`

Comment: What's the linux distribution you're running docker on?  Could be selinux or apparmor preventing dockerd from doing its work.   You could manually mkdir `sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/docker/containers` but I think the docker installer should have taken care of that.  I've read people with those kinds of errors get 'em fixed with a re-install `yum reinstall docker` or `apt-get --reinstall install docker`

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: OK then probably apparmor, you can test and see if it works with apparmor turned off "systemctl stop apparmor" then I'd ask a followup question (this is docker-weeds specific, not devops , I'd ask on askubuntu.com or unix.stackexchange.com) to see what you're supposed to do at that point.

Comment: I already have `/var/lib/docker/containers`. I think docker is just not turning this image into a container..

Comment: @oo92 check syslog or `journalctl -f` while you run `docker run`

Answer (score 1):

This would be the multi-layer approach in docker containers...

```
#Create the base OS image
FROM python:3 AS base

#Update the OS ubuntu image
RUN apt-get -y update

#Install packages
RUN apt-get -y install firefox \
&& apt-get -y install vim

#Create another image layer on top of base to install requirements
FROM base AS requirements

#Install the requirements
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

#Create an intermediate image layer for testing purpose
FROM requirements as test

#Create the build context
COPY /usr/src/my-app /desktop/my-app

#Test the final app
CMD ["python3", "index.py"]
```

Take a look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-combine-multiple-base-images-using-single-dockerfile/